# PhoneGap/Cordova: app crash when set js breakpoint in callback from native on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova(3.2) to develop a web app on iOS, every time I set a breakpoint in javascript(in Safari) of any callback from Cordova native code, the app always crash by a prompt from xCode:

> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1f560ad0: Multiple locks on web thread
>   not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...

I set breakpoint like this:

```
...
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail); // <<< breakpoint here
}
...
```

I doubt it because the webview got locked when Cordova called js, then when my breakpoint was triggered, the webview got second lock.

Does anybody know how I can set breakpoint in js in a callback through native code?

Comment: I am having the same issue with breakpoints in any File API callback. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I have been having the same issue for ages

Comment: Sadly, so far no solution.